# TypeError with default parameters in a function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, typeerror, default-parameters

Im trying to create a function that takes 6 arguments, 3 of which are "optional" given that I tried giving them default values.
This function takes in the 6 values and gives them to another function (defined previously).

Every time I try to run it I get a `TypeError: Coeff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'h'`. I was hoping someone could help me with this!

```
def TSR_inf(coeff, maxmin, d, h='houle', t_h=0, Per=0):

   coeff = coeff
   maxmin = maxmin
   d=d
   h = h
   t_h = t_h
   Per = Per

   Coeff(coeff, maxmin, d, h='houle', t_h=0, Per=0)
```

The `Coeff()` function is defined as such:

```
def Coeff(coeff, maxmin, d, h='houle', t_h=0, Per=0):

  if coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 0 and Per == 0 and h == 'houle':
      Wave_max('x')
  elif coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 0 and Per == 0 and h == 'no houle':
      Wave_max('x', 'no houle')
  elif coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 'reg' and Per == 0 and h == 'houle':
      Wave_max('x', 'reg')
  elif coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 'reg' and Per == 1 and h == 'houle':
      Wave_max('x', 'reg', 1)
  elif coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 'reg' and Per == 1.5 and h == 'houle':
      Wave_max('x', 'reg', 1.5)
  elif coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 'reg' and Per == 2 and h == 'houle':
      Wave_max('x', 'reg', 2)
  elif coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 'irreg' and Per == 0 and h == 'houle':
      Wave_max('x', 'reg')
  elif coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 'irreg' and Per == 1 and h == 'houle':
      Wave_max('x', 'reg', 1)
  elif coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 'irreg' and Per == 1.5 and h == 'houle':
      Wave_max('x', 'reg', 1.5)
  elif coeff == 'wave' and maxmin == 'max' and d == 'x' and t_h == 'irreg' and Per == 2 and h == 'houle':
      Wave_max('x', 'reg', 2)
```

This `Coeff()` function calls another function `def Wave_max(d, h, t_h, Per):` that I won't post here because it is irrelevant (but if you do want it let me know and I'll add it later).

If anyone can spot where I made the mistake that leads to the `TypeError` I won't be veery much appreciated!!

Cheers all! (and thank you in advance!)

Comment: Are you saying that even with the edited version of the code (in which 'h1' appears nowhere), you get an error message referencing 'h1'?

Comment: nooo! I forgot to take that h1 too ahah! Its already gone!

Comment: Thanks - I can't replicate the issue with the code you have.  The problem may lie outside of what you posted: for example, do you have a different Coeff function in another module, and you've imported that instead of the one you show?

Comment: I dont have any other! I imported this Coeff function from another module, and thats it (other than pandas, numpy, etc etc)! I think that I might just Copy-Paste the function to my script! I was just trying to avoid it because my script is now too long and since I need to present the main script, I wanted to keep it under 1500 lines!

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the parameter name is `h` in the `Coeff` function and there is no parameter called `h1` as the error rightly points out.

You probably want to do something like
`Coeff(coeff1, maxmin1, d1, h=h1, t_h=t_h1, Per=Per1)` at the end of the `TSR_inf` function.

Comment: That name was just a way to pin point the location of the error! I had it just with h, and the error persists!

Answer (score 0):

when you pass an keyword argument always use the same argument name as used in the function definition, the issue is your function argument are  `h='houle', t_h=0, Per=0` and you are calling the function with `h1='houle', t_h1=0, Per1=0`

your actual function call should be:

```
Coeff(coeff1, maxmin1, d1, h='houle', t_h=0, Per=0)
```

or as you have already stroed them in variables

```
Coeff(coeff1, maxmin1, d1, h=h1, t_h=t_h1, Per=Per1)
```

and if you want to use h1 as keyword argument in `Coeff` function you can change your function definition as

```
 def  Coeff(coeff1, maxmin1, d1, h='houle', t_h=0, Per=0, **kwargs)
```

and use h1 in the function as

```
kwargs.get('h1')
```

Comment: I edited the post to show how my code is now (I only used, for example, h1 to try to pinpoint the location where the Error occurred)!

Comment: I tried to run the code, it is working fine, your issue might be causing by some thing else

Comment: yeah possibly! Revision time now ahaha! thank you still!